# modelformset_factory: display more fields for specific instances

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm using a modelformset_factory to edit multiple instances of `Product` in the same form:

```
ProductFormSet = modelformset_factory(Product, fields=('code', 'state'))
form_products = ProductFormSet()
```

It works well.

But now I need to display an additional field of the `Product` model in the form but only for a specific instance of `Product`. I'm not sure if it can be done in a simple manner in Django. Is it possible to do so using a `modelformset_factory`?

Comment: I don't have time to write up the full details as an answer right now, let alone test to make sure I'm correct, but I think that should be possible by altering the form's `fields` attribute in the `__init__` method for the form (not formset) class. The instance, if any, will be the `instance` keyword argument to `__init__`.

Comment: Yes, you need to define a new `ModelForm`(kind of `ProductForm`) and override the `__init__` to alter the form dynamically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the form in the modelformset_factory, so create a model form (in forms.py if you have one) override the __init__method to add extra fields. 
I would move the fields from the formsetfactory arguments to the form

in forms.py (assuming you have one)

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):

    model = Product

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


        if 'instance' in kwargs  :
            product = kwargs['instance']

        # to add an extra field, add something like this 
        self.fields['extra_field']  = forms.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        fields = ('code', 'state')
```

Then pass that to your modelformset factory with the form argument

```
ProductFormSet = modelformset_factory(Product,  form=ProductForm )
form_products = ProductFormSet()
```

Comment: I had not seen the `form=myModelForm` attribute before, this is _perfect_!